# Python tips for memory optimization

Tags: python, optimization, memory-management

I need to optimize the RAM usage of my application.
PLEASE spare me the lectures telling me I shouldn't care about memory when coding Python. I have a memory problem because I use very large default-dictionaries (yes, I also want to be fast). My current memory consumption is 350MB and growing. I already cannot use shared hosting and if my Apache opens more processes the memory doubles and triples... and it is expensive.
I have done **extensive profiling** and I know exactly where my problems are.
I have several large (>100K entries) dictionaries with Unicode keys. A dictionary starts at 140 bytes and grows fast, but the bigger problem is the keys. Python optimizes strings in memory (or so I've read) so that lookups can be ID comparisons ('interning' them). Not sure this is also true for unicode strings (I was not able to 'intern' them).
The objects stored in the dictionary are lists of tuples (an_object, an int, an int).

> my_big_dict[some_unicode_string].append((my_object, an_int, another_int))

I already found that it is worth while to split to several dictionaries because the tuples take a lot of space...
I found that I could save RAM by hashing the strings before using them as keys!
But then, sadly, I ran into birthday collisions on my 32 bit system. (side question: is there a 64-bit key dictionary I can use on a 32-bit system?)

Python 2.6.5 on both Linux(production) and Windows. 
Any tips on optimizing memory usage of dictionaries / lists / tuples?
I even thought of using C - I don't care if this very small piece of code is ugly. It is just a singular location.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 2 small comments: I really like the out-of-the-box system level answers, but can they (e.g. a database, even if cached) really compare in performance to a Python dictionary? I'm running real time algorithms and the dictionary is barely fast enough. I'll certainly try memcached and Redis (cool) but will the inter-process communications be fast enough for me? (sorry for adding this now. Hard to optimize for both memory and speed...)   
Also, my dictionary is mostly read-only. Can I use this knowledge somehow?

Comment: "PEP 412: Key-Sharing Dictionary" may be of interest to you. I believe it is included in Python 3.3 http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0412/

Comment: @bcoughlan very cool, thanks! Sadly I need to wait for a 2.7 backport.

Comment: Do you have to use CPython or can you use PyPy (which has some very clever optimisations for collection types and JIT compiles to native...)

Comment: I don't have to do/use anything. Do you think PyPy has a chance to deliver the same or better performance in terms of memory and speed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest the following: store all the values in a DB, and keep an in-memory dictionary with string hashes as keys.  If a collision occurs, fetch values from the DB, otherwise (vast majority of the cases) use the dictionary.  Effectively, it will be a giant cache.

A problem with dictionaries in Python is that they use a lot of space: even an int-int dictionary uses **45-80 bytes** per key-value pair on a 32-bit system.  At the same time, an `array.array('i')` uses only **8 bytes** per a pair of ints, and with a little bit of bookkeeping one can implement a reasonably fast array-based *int → int* dictionary.

Once you have a memory-efficient implementation of an int-int dictionary, split your *string → (object, int, int)* dictionary into three dictionaries and use hashes instead of full strings.  You'll get one *int → object* and two *int → int* dictionaries.  Emulate the *int → object* dictionary as follows: keep a list of objects and store indexes of the objects as values of an *int → int* dictionary.

I do realize there's a considerable amount of coding involved to get an array-based dictionary.  I had had problem similar to yours and I have implemented a reasonably fast, very memory-efficient, generic hash-int dictionary.  [Here's my code](http://code.google.com/p/interwiki-analysis/source/browse/trunk/import-analysis/wikitools/memoptpy.py) (BSD license).  It is array-based (8 bytes per pair), it takes care of key hashing and collision checking, it keeps the array (several smaller arrays, actually) ordered during writes and does binary search on reads.  Your code is reduced to something like:

```
dictionary = HashIntDict(checking = HashIntDict.CHK_SHOUTING)
# ...
database.store(k, v)
try:
    dictionary[k] = v
except CollisionError:
    pass
# ...
try:
    v = dictionary[k]
except CollisionError:
    v = database.fetch(k)
```

The `checking` parameter specifies what happens when a collision occurs: `CHK_SHOUTING` raises `CollisionError` on reads and writes, `CHK_DELETING` returns `None` on reads and remains silent on writes, `CHK_IGNORING` doesn't do collision checking.

What follows is a brief description of my implementation, optimization hints are welcome!  The top-level data structure is a regular dictionary of arrays.  Each array contains up to `2^16 = 65536` integer pairs (square root of `2^32`).  A key `k` and a corresponding value `v` are both stored in `k/65536`-th array.  The arrays are initialized on-demand and kept ordered by keys.  Binary search is executed on each read and write.  Collision checking is an option.  If enabled, an attempt to overwrite an already existing key will remove the key and associated value from the dictionary, add the key to a set of colliding keys, and (again, optionally) raise an exception.

Answer (score 4):

For a web application you should use a database, the way you're doing it you are creating one copy of your dict for each apache process, which is extremely wasteful. If you have enough memory on the server the database table will be cached in memory (if you don't have enough for one copy of your table, put more RAM into the server). Just remember to put correct indices on your database table or you will get bad performance.

Answer (score 2):

I've had situations where I've had a collection of large objects that I've needed to sort and filter by different methods based on several metadata properties. I didn't need the larger parts of them so I dumped them to disk.

As you data is so simple in type, a quick SQLite database might solve all your problems, even speed things up a little.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) or a database to store the data instead of an in-memory dict.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay with the in-memory data store, you could try something like [memcached](http://memcached.org/).

That way, you can use a single in-memory key/value-store from all the Python processes.

There are several python memcached client libraries.

Comment: memcached is lossy, and so is unsuitable for a datastore.

Answer (score 1):

[Redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/) would be a great option here if you have the option to use it on a shared host - similar to memcached, but optimised for data structures. Redis also supports python bindings.

I use it on a day to day basis for number crunching but also in production systems as a datastore and cannot recommend it highly enough.

Also, do you have an option to proxy your app behind nginx instead of using Apache? You might find (if allowed) this proxy/webapp arrangement less hungry on resources.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do extensive optimization and have full control on memory usage you could also write a C/C++ module. Using [Swig](http://www.swig.org/) the code wrapping into Python can be done easily, with some small performance overhead comparing to pure C Python module.