# efficient way to hold and process a big dict in memory in python

Tags: python, dictionary

As I did a bit test, a python dict of int=>int (different value) of 30 million items can easily eats >2G memory on my mac. Since I work with only int to int dict, is there any better solution than using python dict?

Some requirements I need are,

1. more memory efficient at holding tens of million level of int to int items
2. basic dict methods like fetching value by key and iterating all items
3. easy to serialise to string / binary would be a plus

Update,
 4. easy to get subset by given keys, like d.fromkeys([...])

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any assumptions you can make wrt. the keys? E.g. are they contiguous? Are they entered in order? Is O(lg n) lookup performance acceptable?

Comment: Python objects are quite large, but I don't think they're large enough to blow a dict of 30 million integer pairs up to 2 GB. I'd expect more in the order of a few hundred megabytes. How did you determine those numbers? And are you using 64 bit Python, or are your integers particular large (> several billion)?

Comment: I don't know if this is a valid suggestion or not, but consider using another language. Python is slow and very memory consuming. Consider C++

Comment: @JasonHsu can you post a few entries of the data you are inserting into the dict ? It would help us to understand how big are the keys->values.

Comment: @delnan, @Srika\ Appal, it's a simple dict like {1:30000001, 2:30000002, ..., 30000000:60000000}. Not really realistic but I just created it for test purpose. I simply use "for i in range(30000000): d[i]=i+30000000" on macbook 64bit, python 2.7.5 without calling any GC explicitly. As double tested, it used 3.06G : )

Comment: @The-IT, It would be very nice to have some C-based library which have a python interface and can easily be glue'd with my existing python logics. : )

Comment: @larsmans, Actually key are userid or hash of string-typed user id, value would be some counter or hash of string value. Some heavy process would be similar to d.fromkeys([u1,u2,...]) where d is a million level big dict, for getting a subset of a user cohort.

Comment: Not sure if it's an option to use Numpy. Any one can advice? thanks.

Comment: If the keys are contiguous (like in your example) it would be easy to use a numpy array. Let the keys be indexes! Your example would become `numpy.arange(30000000, 60000001, dtype=numpy.int32)` or something similar. If you need to detect non-existent keys, you could use NaN or some sort of sentinel value that isn't likely to appear in your actual data (perhaps `-1`).

Comment: @Blckknght, the B-tree based index still gives me a Log(n) complexity on speed, however I will be absolutely consider it if can't find a better hashtable based solution. Thanks for your information.

Comment: @delnan: Just tested, it's definitely 3.05GB here. It's not unreasonable on a 64-bit Python: a pointer is 8 bytes; the dict holds 2 pointers per entry, and a single `int` is probably 24 bytes (8 byte refcnt, 8 byte type pointer, 8 byte `long` value). So that's 64 bytes per entry right there. The remainder of the space usage may be attributed to overallocation of the dictionary.

Comment: @nneonneo 64-bit Python was one of the things I considered but didn't want to assume. Yeah, it adds up now.

Comment: Just did the test on 32-bit Python; it's 1.46GB. Clearly, huge numbers of `int`s are an area where 64-bit Python sorely loses.

Comment: @nneonneo, please checkout my latest test about Judy array at the bottom. I cannot set it as answer within 2 days. : )

Comment: @JasonHsu: Back-of-the-envelope calculation suggests that a roll-your-own implementation using a hashtable of 32-bit ints would be just 300MB (implemented on a simple array of [int,int] pairs, with a load factor of 0.8). You can implement that pretty easily on top of `array`, or implement it in C for raw performance. A data structure specifically tuned to your application is certain to outperform any generic container if implemented properly.

Comment: @nneonneo, Python consider itself as a "glue language" so such "high density" data processing work would be left to lower-level C/C++ library and "glue" them using sth like Cython : ) It's not a big lose when come to 64 bit since it's a tradeoff to allow a much bigger memory space (if I understand it correctly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judy-array based solution seems the option I should look into. I'm still looking for a good implementation that can be used by Python. Will update later.

Update,

finally I'm experimenting a Judy array wrapper at http://code.google.com/p/py-judy/ .
Seems no any document there but I tried to find its methods simply by dir(...) its package and object, however it works.

Same experiment it eats ~986MB at ~1/3 of standard dict by using judy.JudyIntObjectMap. It also provides JudyIntSet which in some special scenario will save much more memory since it doesn't need to reference to any real Python object as value comparing to JudyIntObjectMap.

(As tested further as below, JudyArray simply uses several MB to tens of MB, most of ~986MB is actually used by value objects in Python memory space.)

Here's some code if it helps for you,

```
>>> import judy
>>> dir(judy)
['JudyIntObjectMap', 'JudyIntSet', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> a=judy.JudyIntObjectMap()
>>> dir(a)
['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__value_sizeof__', 'by_index', 'clear', 'get', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'pop']
>>> a[100]=1
>>> a[100]="str"
>>> a["str"]="str"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'non-integer keys not supported'
>>> for i in xrange(30000000):
...     a[i]=i+30000000   #finally eats ~986MB memory
...
```

Update,

ok, a JudyIntSet of 30M int as tested.

```
>>> a=judy.JudyIntSet()
>>> a.add(1111111111111111111111111)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: we only support integers in the range [0, 2**64-1]
```

It totally uses only 5.7MB to store 30M sequential int array [0,30000000) which may due to JudyArray's auto compression. Above 709MB is bcz I used range(...) instead of more proper xrange(...) to generate the data.

So the size of the core JudyArray with 30M int is simply ignorable.

If anyone knows a more complete Judy Array wrapper implementation please let me know, since this wrapper only wraps JudyIntObjectMap and JudyIntSet. For int-int dict, JudyIntObjectMap still requires real python object. If we only do counter_add and set on the values, it would be a good idea to store int of values in C space rather than using python object. Hope someone be interested to create or introduce one : )

Answer (score 10):

There are at least two possibilities:

**arrays**

You could try using two arrays. One for the keys, and one for the values so that index(key) == index(value)

**Updated 2017-01-05:** use 4-byte integers in array.

An array would use less memory. On a 64-bit FreeBSD machine with python compiled with clang, an array of 30 million integers uses around 117 MiB.

These are the python commands I used:

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 28 2016, 20:51:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 3.8.0 (tags/RELEASE_380/final 262564)] on freebsd11
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from array import array
>>> a = array('i', xrange(30000000))
>>> a.itemsize
4
```

After importing array, `ps` reports:

```
USER     PID %CPU %MEM   VSZ  RSS TT  STAT STARTED    TIME COMMAND
 rsmith 81023  0.0  0.2  35480   8100  0  I+   20:35     0:00.03 python (python2.7)
```

After making the array:

```
USER     PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ    RSS TT  STAT STARTED    TIME COMMAND
rsmith 81023 29.0  3.1 168600 128776  0  S+   20:35     0:04.52 python (python2.7)
```

The Resident Set Size is reported in 1 KiB units, so (128776 - 8100)/1024 = 117 MiB

With list comprehensions you could easily get a list of indices where the key meets a certain condition. You can then use the indices in that list to access the corresponding values...

**numpy**

If you have numpy available, using that is faster, has lots more features and and uses slightly less RAM:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 10 2013, 19:54:11) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 3.1 ((branches/release_31 156863))] on freebsd9
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(0, 30000000, dtype=np.int32)
```

From `ps`: 6700 KiB after starting Python, 17400 KiB after import numpy and 134824 KiB after creating the array. That's around 114 MiB.

Furthermore, numpy supports [record arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html);

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 10 2013, 19:54:11) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 3.1 ((branches/release_31 156863))] on freebsd9
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros((10,), dtype=('i4,i4'))
>>> a
array([(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0),
       (0, 0), (0, 0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
>>> a.dtype.names
('f0', 'f1')
>>> a.dtype.names = ('key', 'value')
>>> a
array([(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0),
       (0, 0), (0, 0)], 
      dtype=[('key', '<i4'), ('value', '<i4')])
>>> a[3] = (12, 5429)
>>> a
array([(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (12, 5429), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0),
       (0, 0), (0, 0)], 
      dtype=[('key', '<i4'), ('value', '<i4')])
>>> a[3]['key']
12
```

Here you can access the keys and values separately;

```
>>> a['key']
array([ 0,  0,  0, 12,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, my fault to miss some critical requirement that k-v search, getting subset by given keys are still important. so I can't simply store them into 2 arrays.

Comment: @JasonHsu: how about numpy record arrays then?

Comment: I'll try out some Judy-array based solution first as replied below, if not works then back to trying Numpy since ~O(1) look-up time still important to me. Thanks for your info. : )

Comment: O(1) is limiting your options quite a bit. Hash maps, arrays that you don't have to search (if keys are a given range so you can just use them as indexes) are the obvious options.

Comment: This is an incredible answer and deserves way more upvotes than it has.

Comment: You are unfair to `array.array` because you compare 64bit integer array to 32bit integer `np.array`. For the most 64bit systems 'l' means 64bit signed integer. You can check the item size using `a=array.array('l')` and then `a.itemsize` which most probably would be 8. `np.array` is still a better choice because there is much more functionality working out of the box .

Comment: @ead Good point! I've updated my answer to use 4-byte integers with `array`.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer added if what you want is just an dictionary-like counter that's easy to use.

[High performance Counter object from Python standard library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 1):

If we knew a bit more about how it would be used it might be easier to suggest good solutions.
You say you want to fetch values by key and iterate over all of them, but nothing about if you need to insert/delete data.

One pretty efficient way of storing data is with the [array](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) module. If you do not need to insert/remove data, you could simply have two arrays. The "key" array would be sorted and you could do binary search for the right key. Then you'd just pick the value from the same position in the other array.

You could easily encapsulate that in a class that behaves dict-like. I don't know if there is a ready solution for this somewhere, but it should not be terribly difficult to implement. That should help you avoid having lots of python objects which consume memory.

But you might have other requirements that makes such a solution impractical/impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll still need to get subset of the big dict by given key set, like d.fromkeys([...]). It's ok to just scan and filter on the key array, and inserting with duplication prevention... so array is not an option for me.