# Possible to use Judy array in Java?

Tags: java, hashtable, judy-array

I'm impressed by the memory foot print of Judy Array in one of my Python experiment 
([another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041848/efficient-way-to-hold-and-process-a-big-dict-in-memory-in-python/18042060?noredirect=1#18042060)). Is there anyway to use it in Java (the c lib or any ported version)? If no, any alternative can provide similar benefit?

Comment: It is not difficult to implement them in Java, but the gain is very small. As those are simple radix trees, a common choice is to implement them using objects and thus you will inherit the object overhead etc. You can try to implement them with byte buffers though.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasJungblut, is there any implementation i can look into? since I didn't find an obvious one.